# NSOutlineView reloadData is crashing

Tags: cocoa, crash, interface-builder, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView for which I do a reloadData:

```
[myOutlineView reloadData];
```

myOutlineView is bound from InterfaceBuilder. This works fine on my computer but not on a beta testers to which machine I have no access.
His crashlog shows that:

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_rowViews should not be NULL at this point'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff888fd66c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f1e376e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff888fd44a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ba8e3a9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff85e54b24 -[NSTableRowData _removeRowViewForRow:] + 472
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff85d3e0dd -[NSTableRowData _removeVisibleRows] + 93
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff85d3dd4a -[NSTableRowData removeAllKnownSubviews] + 139
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff85d3dafb -[NSTableRowData reloadData] + 74
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff85d3d968 -[NSTableView reloadData] + 175
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff85efb77c -[NSOutlineView reloadData] + 578
10  PhotoStream2Folder                  0x0000000105b668d1 -[PSFAppDelegate scanSharedStreams] + 2249
```

What can I do to further understand why the _rowViews is nil ?
How can I test the _rowViews before launching reloadData ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I see this occasionally to when calling reloadData on my NSOutlineView.

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore, but am not sure how it was solved (almost 3 years ago !). Maybe I recreated the links in IB.